# Spring damaged pdf under resources/static

Tags: spring, pdf, spring-boot

My spring boot app is not able to correctly show PDF file. However the images are showing just fine.

I am storing the static files under `src/main/resources/static`

I can access an image file with url `http://localhost:8080/img/sample.jpg`
This file is located at `src/main/resources/static/img/sample.jpg`

I **cannot** access pdf file with url `http://localhost:8080/pdf/file.pdf`
This file is located at `src/main/resources/static/pdf/file.pdf`
The browser complains that the pdf cannot be loaded

It is not browser support issue because when I drag the pdf file directly to the browser, it shows on the browser correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following in **pom.xml** file solves the problem

```
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
```

It turns out the pdf file got "changed" after packaging because of the resource filtering.
Hope it helps somebody who came across this problem.